# Poles of integral $\oint_D\left(\frac{\cos(\pi z/2)}{(z^2+i)(\sin^{2}(\pi z)}\right)\,dz$

Tags: integration, complex-analysis, residue-calculus, curves

Which are the poles of this integral and what order do they have?

$$\oint_D\left(\frac{\cos(\pi z/2)}{(z^2+i)(\sin^{2}(\pi z)}\right)\,dz$$

where $D$ is $|z|<3/2$.

In my opinion the should be $z= -\frac{\sqrt(2)}{2}+i\frac{\sqrt(2)}{2}$,

$z= \frac{\sqrt(2)}{2}-i\frac{\sqrt(2)}{2}$

poles of the **first** order.

and $z=0$ pole of the **second** order

and  $z=1$ pole of the **first** order.

But wolfram doesn't find those two. do you know which are the poles for this function ?

Answer (score 1):

It is probably best to write the function so that you do not have shared zeroes of numerator and denominator. We have $\sin(\pi z )=2\sin \frac{\pi z}2 \cos\frac{\pi z}2$ so your function is 
$$f(z) = \frac{1}{4(z^2+i)\sin^2\frac{\pi z}2\cos \frac{\pi z }2}
$$
This clearly has a simple pole at the zeroes of $z^2+i$ that you calculated correctly above, simple poles at the zeroes of $\cos \frac{\pi z}2$, so at $+1$ and $-1$, and double poles at the zeroes of $\sin \frac{\pi z}2$. The only zero of that function in $D$ is $0$.

So summing up, all you have missed is an additional simple pole at $-1$.